# Chrome Extension Notification Demo Not Popping Up

Tags: json, google-chrome, notifications, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome Extension, which will have a pop up in it, however when I go to use the Notifications Demo App and install it in Chrome it doesn't display any notifications. I don't know if there is something wrong with the sample app which is here : [enter link description here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/samples.html#f799e26ceef2367cf836f24bcb47df4398b0df58) or that it's become outdated and thus it's a permissions problem. Any help would be appreciated as previous questions I found don't seem to have a notification problem in regards to extensions, but instead to putting them on their blog or the likes.

Thanks,

Comment: Demo works fine for me on v.13. Maybe you have notifications disabled in your settings?

Comment: Works for me too. As @serg suggests, have a look at your settings chrome://settings/content (at the bottom).

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem.  It's a bug in Chrome:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=77682

Going into chrome://chrome/settings > Content Settings > Notifications and selecting "Allow all sites to show desktop notifications" is the only fix I can recommend right now.